# calculate gradient directions

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, gradient

I want calculate angles of gradients from depth map and group it for some directions (8 sectors)
But my function calculates only first 3 directions

```
cv::Mat calcAngles(cv::Mat dimg)//dimg is depth map
{   
    const int directions_num = 8;//number of directions
    const int degree_grade = 360;
    int range_coeff = 255 / (directions_num + 1);//just for visualize
    cv::Mat x_edge, y_edge, full_edge, angles;
    dimg.copyTo(x_edge);
    dimg.copyTo(y_edge);
    dimg.copyTo(full_edge);
        //compute gradients

    Sobel( dimg, x_edge,    CV_8U, 1, 0, 5, 1, 19, 4 );
    Sobel( dimg, y_edge,    CV_8U, 0, 1, 5, 1, 19, 4 );
    Sobel( dimg, full_edge, CV_8U, 1, 1, 5, 1, 19, 4 );

    float freq[directions_num + 1];//for collect direction's frequency
    memset(freq, 0, sizeof(freq));

    angles = cv::Mat::zeros(dimg.rows, dimg.cols, CV_8U);//store directions here
    for(int i = 0; i < angles.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < angles.cols; j++)
        {
            angles.at<uchar>(i, j) = (((int)cv::fastAtan2(y_edge.at<uchar>(i, j), x_edge.at<uchar>(i, j))) / (degree_grade/directions_num) + 1
                ) * (dimg.at<uchar>(i, j) ? 1 : 0);//fastatan returns values from 0 to 360, if i not mistaken. I want group angles by directions_num sectors. I use first 'direction' (zero value) for zero values from depth map (zero value at my depth map suggest that it is bad pixel)  
            freq[angles.at<uchar>(i, j)] += 1;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < directions_num + 1; i++) 
    {
        printf("%2.2f\t", freq[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    angles *= range_coeff;//for visualization
    return angles;
}
```

Out from one of the frames:

```
47359.00        15018.00        8199.00 6224.00 0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

(first value is "zero pixel", next is number of gradients in n-place but only 3 are not zero)

Visualization

[image]

Is there way out? Or these result is OK?
PS Sorry for my writing mistakes. English in not my native language.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your function with a debugger to see what the problem is?

Comment: @nijansen Yes i do. I found that this value (int)cv::fastAtan2(y_edge.at<uchar>(i, j), x_edge.at<uchar>(i, j)) every time less or equal than 90

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used `CV_8U` type for `Sobel` output. It is unsigned integer 8 bit. So it can store only positive values. That's why `fastAtan2` returns less or equal than 90. Change type to `CV_16S` and use `short` type for accessing the elements:

```
cv::Sobel(dimg, x_edge, CV_16S, 1, 0, 5, 1, 19, 4);
cv::Sobel(dimg, y_edge, CV_16S, 0, 1, 5, 1, 19, 4);

cv::fastAtan2(y_edge.at<short>(i, j), x_edge.at<short>(i, j))
```

Comment: Thank you. I forget about types